# Tortoise svn history of commits

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checkouted svn repo at the beginning of march and I need to see revisions from the end of the previous year. Nevertheless when I open dialog TortoiseSVN -> show log, I'm able to see only revisions that were done after my checkout. Is there any way, how to force tortoise svn, to download logs of the previous revisions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the **Log** with `show log` an uncheck `Stop copy/rename` (in the lower left corner of dialog). If you want to see more logs click for example `Show All`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If are viewing `show log` from your working copy, you will not be able to see the previous revisions. Instead, open the URL in Tortoise SVN > Repo browser > Navigate to the required folder/file > Right Click and Click on Show Log.

Comment: "you will not be able to see the previous revisions". From my point of view this is not fully correct. Please see my answer and correct me if I wrong.

Comment: Correct Micha.. My Mistake.. Thanks